# How can Fetch Excel data into react native App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have Excel Sheet for Attendance and I want that data into my Mobile App.
Is it Possible to fetch those data in my mobile app? so I can see weekly attendance on my app.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/excel-connect-react.rst#:~:text=To%20work%20with%20live%20Excel,endpoints%20for%20the%20Excel%20data.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Is it paid Subsription for Cdata?

Comment: You can google for more options

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.